# How to add specific information in a csv file in specific row and column?

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I have a script in bash that in some part of the code i need to add to a csv specific information in row and column specific, for example :

The format of my csv is the next :

```
Columns1 Columns2 Columns3 Columns4 Columns5 Columns6 Columns7 Columns8
animals   value2   value3   value4   value5   value6   value7   value8
bird      value2   value3   value4   value5   value6   value7   value8
```

So, I need that when the script found a value for example :

```
grep "animals" myfile.csv
```

add some information for example in the row with the value "animals" add or replace the value in the column5

In all my script.sh always I need to add several information many times in a specific range.

I would appreciate that the solution was in bash

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily with `awk`:

```
awk -v M=match -v R=replace 'BEGIN {FS=","; OFS=","} $1==M {$5=R} {print}' infile.csv > outfile.csv
```

Comment: Woow this is works, really, I had been searching for days this answer, but only one little detail, when i run this command in a terminal , it works but does no add the information to the csv file, what parameter i need to add ?

Comment: I just updated the code to show how to write the output to a new file. You can then rename the new file to the same name as the old file if you'd like.

Comment: ok, i see, but i have a little problem, after executed this comand the line where is replace a value, it is shows without "," , like this :                                        animals value2 value3 value4 newvaluel value6 value7 value8                                   and when create a new file (> outfile.csv) i have the value of the row modified in a cell instead of severals cells

Comment: Sorry about that. I've edited it so that both the input and output field separators are set properly.

Comment: Thanks so much for you help with this, i really appreciate your help =), only one question more, the word "animal" could be replace with a variable ?

Comment: Yep. You can specify variables with -v. I've edited it to show both the match and replace strings. You can use shell variables instead of strings for M= and R= in that case.

Comment: Thanks again Misandrist

Comment: Absolutely! Any time!